# P5.JS .show() is not a function, why?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Not sure if i'm getting the scope wrong but iv'e tried moving the function around a bit but it just gives me that is not a function error.

```js
let bubbles = [];
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 bubbles[i] = new Bubble(200, 200, 40)
 }
}




function draw() {
  background(0);
 for (i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){
  bubbles[i].show();
}}
 
 function show() {
 stroke(20);
 strokeWeight(2);
 fill(random(255), 0, random(255))
 ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2)

}

class Bubble {
 constuctor(x, y, r){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.r = r;
}}
```

Comment: Move `function show(){ ... }` inside `class Bubble { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments by Rabbid76, your main problem is that you are calling a function within the `Bubble` object which doesn't exist. So you should pop that into the `Bubble` class:

```
class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, r){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
    
  show() {
    stroke(20);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(random(255), 0, random(255))
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2)
  }
}
```

Also, just so you know you misspelt `constructor` and if you're using the p5 online editor it doesn't flag it as an error, it thinks you've defined a new function called `constuctor` it is completely valid syntax.

One more thing, you are passing in the `x` and `y` location of each bubble as `200, 200`, which basically means each bubble is going to be on top of each other, I'm assuming you'd want them to be spread out around the screen:

```
bubbles[i] = new Bubble(random(width), random(height), 20);
```

Oh and also, you may want to store the r,g,b colours in the `Bubble` object so it doesn't choose a new colour each frame!